# What are the static requirements of Swift protocol?

Tags: swift, objective-c

When trying to use code from ObjC in Swift, I encountered the following Swift error:

```
'myClass & myProtocol' cannot be used as a type conforming to protocol 'myProtocol' because 'myProtocol' has static requirements
```

The code looks roughly like this:

```
@interface FooGenericContainer <T : MyClass < MyProtocol > *> : MyClass
```

```
func asFoo() -> FooGenericContainer<MyClass & MyProtocol> { /// <-- error here
  ....
}
```

```
@protocol MyProtocol <NSObject, NSCopying, NSMutableCopying, AnotherProtocol>
@end

...

@protocol AnotherProtocol <NSObject, NSCopying, NSMutableCopying>

+ (NSDictionary *)method1;

@optional

+ (NSDictionary *)method2;

@end
```

What are "static requirements" of a protocol, are these the class methods it have?

How can I overcome this error?

Can I return `FooGenericContainer` without specifying the generic type?

Comment: What does `myProtocol` look like?

Comment: Well, both `method1` and `method2` are static requirements.

Comment: @Sweeper Are there other kinds of "static requirements"? I don't understand why there is a problem here and how to overcome it.

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33112559/protocol-doesnt-conform-to-itself) for an explanation.

Comment: I still don't see the definition for the MyProtocol Class. How does EVDInputModel factor into this? I don't see it being used anywhere.

Comment: @Biclops Updated the question. Sorry for the confusion, copy pasted real code and forgot to translate it into the example.

Answer (score 1):

I got past the error by adding `<MyProtocol>` To the `MyClass` definition

This is the code I used

```
// copied from a header that's included in the bridging header in OBJC

@protocol AnotherProtocol <NSObject, NSCopying, NSMutableCopying>
+ (NSDictionary *)method1;
@optional
+ (NSDictionary *)method2;
@end

@protocol MyProtocol <NSObject, NSCopying, NSMutableCopying, AnotherProtocol>
@end

//  Note: if I didn't include '<MyProtocol>' it would give me the static requirement error
@interface MyClass <MyProtocol>
@end

@interface FooGenericContainer <T: MyClass<MyProtocol> *> : MyClass
@end
```

Then in swift

```
// I made this optional just to get it to compile
func asFoo() -> FooGenericContainer<MyClass & MyProtocol>? {
    return nil
}
```

Comment: If this doesn't work what does your class declaration look like for MyClass?

Comment: My memory is hazy with obj-c but I think the @interface MyClass <MyProtocol> bit is the declaration.